# Cannot find symbol error for variables My2DTableCoordinate and Arraylist?

Tags: java

Arraylist is imported at top of class like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

however it still errors from the code

```
coordinates.add(ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height));
```

which is taken from a method called

```
public My2DTable(int height) {
coordinates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>>(height);
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  coordinates.add(ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height));
}
```

the 2d arraylist is declared as

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>> coordinates;
```

thanks to @ycf_l

Comment: To add an array to another you have to initialize with new like so `coordinates.add(new ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height));`

Comment: thank you @YCF_L that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing 'new' keyword.  Also, this new one is presumably the width, since the outer one was the height.

```
coordinates.add(new ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height));
```

I would argue, however, that you generally should not declare variables to be a specific implementation of List.  The only time you mention the specific implementation is when you create it.  As long as you always declare things to be only as specific as you need to, you are more free to change later when you find out that a different implementation will have better performance.  So I'd suggest the following.

```
class Foo {
    List<List<My2DTableCoordinate>> coordinates;

    public My2DTable(int height, int width) {
        coordinates = new ArrayList<>(height);
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
          coordinates.add(new ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(width));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot missing here. Where is `coordinates` defined? Also `ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height)` should be `new ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height)`.

It would help a great deal if we knew exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: My2DTable.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      coordinates.add(ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height));
                      ^
  symbol:   variable ArrayList
  location: class My2DTable
My2DTable.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      coordinates.add(ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>(height));
                                ^
  symbol:   variable My2DTableCoordinate
  location: class My2DTable
2 errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the class `My2DTableCoordinate` or import it

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that My2DTableCoordinate is being called as a constructor method

Comment: what does that mean ? My2DTableCoordinate is a type not a variable.